# s3 pre-signed url for buckets in us-east-1, us-west-1, us-west-2 missing fields

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to generate s3 pre-signed url so that I can PUT objects into my buckets from the client side. My regions of interest initially were:

1. ap-northeast-2 (seoul)
2. ap-south-1 (mumbai)
3. us-east-1
4. us-west-2

Below is the code I use to get the signed url:

```js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");

const region_name = "x-region";
const upload_bucket = "bucket-in-x-region";
AWS.config.update({ region: region_name });
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

async function getPresignedUrl() {
  const random_id = uuidv4();
  const obj_key = `${random_id}.png`;
  const s3Params = {
    Bucket: upload_bucket,
    Key: obj_key,
    Expires: 60,
    ContentType: "image/png",
    ACL: "public-read",
  };
  const presigned_url = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise("putObject", s3Params);
  return presigned_url;
}

getPresignedUrl().then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Buckets in ap-northeast-2 and ap-south-1 returns a **WORKING** signed-url with the fields:
**Content-Type, X-Amz-Algorithm, X-Amz-Credential, X-Amz-Date, X-Amz-Expires, X-Amz-Security-Token, X-Amz-Signature, X-Amz-SignedHeaders, x-amz-acl**

However the all buckets I tried based in regions: us-east-1, us-west-1 and us-west-2 returns a **NON WORKING** url with only the following fields:
**Content-Type, Expires, Signature, x-amz-acl**

When I run this code in lambda, the invocation role has a policy with the following statement:

```json
  {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name-mumbai/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name-seoul/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name-useast/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name-uswest/*",
            ]
        }
```

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you running this function inside AWS Lambda? If yes, can you verify that the S3 client is in the global scope of the function?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @AllanChua. I run this function inside AWS lambda (with an invocation role having necessary policy), as well as in my local environment. In both cases, I get a url missing those fields only for buckets created in the 3 us regions. For confirmation test, a test-bucket in canaca ca-central-1 also returned a correct url.

Comment: Adriel, are you sure that the lambda function used to execute this pre-signed URL code is provided enough permission on all these US-based buckets?

Comment: I updated the question to include the policy statement applied to the role

Comment: @AdrielNiyodusaba how do you know it is not working? Did you get any errors? The fields do not seem to be an issue to my understanding. I haven't tried the JS SDK, but with boto3 for python, I only get `key`, `signature`, and `expires`, or `policy`.

Comment: @RegisterSole the url was not valid, because when I sent a PUT request to it, I got 403. I confirmed that it was invalid by trying to generate a signed-url passing non-existing bucket name in s3 params and the returned url came with headers: Content-Type, Expires, Signature, x-amz-acl

Answer (score 3):

Add `signatureVersion: 'v4'` in AWS config and it should work:

```
AWS.config.update({ region: region_name, signatureVersion: 'v4' });
```